# Writing cross-platform Unity3D plugins using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, xamarin

Is it possible to write cross-platform Unity3D plugins (specifically for android and ios) using the Xamarin APIs?

If yes, what would be the procedure to go about doing it? Are you aware of any documentation or reference that might be useful?

Unity still doesn't provide a lot of native functionality as Xamarin does. I'm asking this because it just makes sense minimizing the learning curve for developing unity plugins. After a lot of experimentation, I've just begun understanding the intricacies of C#. If I have to learn two other languages (Java and Objective-C) that would greatly impede my progress.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific, maybe a case ? You can use dlls plugins w/o xamarin w/o problem as is.

Comment: Can you give an example of what Xamarin gives you that MonoDevelop doesn't?

Comment: Probably not.  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html describes plugins as native libraries.  What native code do you need to create a plugin for?

Comment: At the time of posting of this question I was looking for plugins for Text-To-Speech and Encryption.

I apologize for the late reply. Somehow this went unnoticed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is opensourcing the Xamarin SDK, so combined with Mono for Android (that Unity most probably uses), you could soon be closer to your goal

BTW, they're also changing Mono's licensing model to the more permissive "MIT License" and hosting it under the .NET Foundation

Answer (score -3):

Xamarin and Unity MonoDevelop are separate project. Xamarin doesnt support Unity. If you want a crossplatform plugin you could use C++ read:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Comment: MonoDevelop is an IDE, and has nothing to do with this question.